# Can't tab to form elements without clicking first

Tags: html, css, dom

I'm working to make a page accessibility compliant.  I have a few form elements that I can only reach once I click on an element in that form.  If I load the page and hit tab, it cycles between a few links at the top of the page.  If I click on one of the form elements, it gets focus, then I can tab to the other form elements.  If I tab out of the form, I can't return with out clicking.  Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Sample code would be nice.

Comment: I can work on an example that has the same issue.  Can't upload actual code unfortunately.

Comment: A lot is involved in making forms 508 compliant. Tab sequence which is your problem has a lot of factors that could break it or make it, buttons, dropdowns, the jquery tab sequence, and more. If you could replicate the error with dummy data I can look at it

Answer (score 1):

I would try to attach the attribute `tabindex` to the form inputs.

```
<input type="text" tabindex="3"></input>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp

Comment: This seems to work, even though tabindex="0" did not work.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: When I apply tabindex="3" to all the form elements, it breaks all tabbing and only the body ever gets focus, when i use document.activeElement

Comment: You will have to increment the tabindex for each item you want the user to tab through. I'd set tabindex 1,2,3,4... to the menu and the next values to the form. Form might be tabindex 6,7,8,9

Comment: It seems the tab order is being broken by disabled form elements.  Creating a form with no disabled elements works properly,  while I can not tab past disabled elements. Working on a JS fiddle example

Comment: If at all possible, tabindex="0" should be used. https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex#zero-negative-one